# How to publish an asp.net project with a connection to a DB2 database?

Tags: asp.net, db2, db2-400

I'm developing a project in asp.net that contains a connection to a iseries db2 database; locally the project works because I already have the **IBM iseries Access for Windows** driver installed in the machine where the project is developed, the problem is when I want to publish it on a server, the connection to the database doesn't work, I suppose the error happens beacuse doesn't exist any driver in the server. What can I do to connect the project with the database if I want to host it on a server for example In Microsoft Azure?

Currently the code to connect with the database is similar to this:

```
string provider = "DataSource=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;userid=user;password=pass;";

iDB2Connection cnn = new iDB2Connection(provider);
string sentencia = "select * from DTA.Customer FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY";

iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(sentencia, cnn );

iDB2DataReader drDB2;

cnn.Open();

drDB2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
while (drDB2.Read())
{
    //Console.WriteLine(drDB2.GetString(i));
}
drDB2.Close();
cnn.Close();
```

Comment: Sounds like you know. Install the driver on the target server.

Comment: If you want to connect to an i-series Db2 database from Azure, you will need the same (or equivalent) iSeries Access driver installed on Azure, and that will need to be licensed, and you may also need a secure-gateway between Azure and your iSeries.

Comment: @mao Do you know how to install that driver?

Comment: Consider isolating the code to access the iSeries from your project.  We do it 2 ways.  1 - have a Windows Service running on a local server that monitors a Service Bus and executes commands, the asp.net project uses the Service Bus to send the commands.  2 - create a web service on the iSeries and have the asp.net project utilize this web service.